# Compiled with problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with react-router-dom and Prompt. The problem is `Prompt' (imported as 'Prompt')` was not found. Has something changed in the new versions?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/ContactPage.css';
import { Prompt } from 'react-router-dom';

class ContactPage extends React.Component {
    state = {
        value: ''
    }
    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            value: '',
        })
    }
    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value,
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='contact'>
                <form>
                    <h3>Send a form</h3>
                    <textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='write something'></textarea>
                    <button onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>Send</button>
                </form>
                <Prompt when={true} message={"You did not end your form. Are you sure you want to change a page? All data will be lost"} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ContactPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has [a guide for upgrading from v5 to v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#prompt-is-not-currently-supported) which says:

> `<Prompt>` is not currently supported
>
> `<Prompt>` from v5 (along with `usePrompt` and `useBlocker` from the
> v6 betas) are not included in the current released version of v6. We
> decided we'd rather ship with what we have than take even more time to
> nail down a feature that isn't fully baked. We will absolutely be
> working on adding this back in to v6 at some point in the near future,
> but not for our first stable release of 6.x.

Stick to v5 if you want to use it.

Comment: Thanks,
So there is no another option to use? Cuz i want to get something like safeguard, is something has been written in input, there will be a alert that "your changes will be lost"
And second, <Route component={<ErrorPage />  how to use this whenever someone write wrong path, there will be what a ErrorPage

Comment: The documentation is quite clear that it is not a feature in v6. As I said, you can use v5 instead.